# Getting the last pixel with certain number of occurences

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have an image where I'm trying to return the first pixel which occurs more times than some threshold (i.e. 4), and the last pixel which also occurs more times than some threshold.

For the firs part (first pixel), I did the following:

```
for i in range(0,80):
    if (img == i).sum() >= 4:
        begin = i
        break
```

For the second part (last pixel), I did the following:

```
idx = 0
for i in reversed(pixel_frequency):
    if i >= 4:
        end = reveresed(begin_to_end_pixel_frequency)[idx]
        break
    else:
        idx = idx + 1
```

The above lists in the second part came from this code:

```
for i in range(begin,255):
    begin_to_end.append(i)
    begin_to_end_pixel_frequency.append((img == i).sum())
```

The first part works fine, but the second part gives me the wrong answer? It seems I'm making a problem in the way I'm indexing the items in the *reversed* list?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `end = reveresed(begin_to_end_pixel_frequency)[idx]` doing? Iirc, `reversed` cannot be indexed.

Comment: Any reason why you're using a `for` loop for the first part? It seems not an efficient approach. Also, it's unclear why your range is `(0, 80)`. Does this mean you have a grayscale image where there're only 80 unique values?